# Delphi XML Parsing

Tags: xml, delphi, parsing

This my xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <code>0</code>
        <description>Success</description>
        <Logs>
            <msisdn status="0">88888888</msisdn>
            <msisdn status="0">99999999</msisdn>
        </Logs>
    </Response>
```

Now, I need to get status value.

Here is my code;

```
nodes_row := xml.selectNodes('/Response/Logs/msisdn');
    for i := 0 to nodes_row.length - 1 do
    begin
      node := nodes_row.item[i];
    end;
```

I got node , but I don't know how to get status value.

Comment: `node.Attributes["status"]` ?

Comment: node.Attributes[0] is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using `MSXML`, you should be able to use:

```
nodes_row.item[i].attributes.getNamedItem('status').Text
```

or via AttributeNodes:

```
nodes_row.item[i].AttributeNodes.Nodes['status'].Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `xml` is an `IDOMNodeSelect` interface (from the `Xml.Xmldom` unit) that you have retrieved from an `IXMLNode.DOMNode` property, then `IDOMNodeSelect.selectNodes()` returns an `IDOMNodeList` containing `IDOMNode` elements.  `IDOMNode` has an `attributes` property that returns an `IDOMNamedNodeMap`, which has an `items[]` property if you want to access a value by index and a `getNamedItem()` method if you want to access a value by name.  Both return an `IDOMNode`, which has a `nodeValue` property property:

```
nodes_row := xml.selectNodes('/Response/Logs/msisdn');
for i := 0 to nodes_row.length - 1 do
begin
  value := nodes_row.item[i].attributes[0].nodeValue;
  //or:
  value := nodes_row.item[i].attributes.getNamedItem('status').nodeValue;
  //...
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

node.Attributes[0].text;

It is worked

Comment: I suggest you use another solution. Relying on position [0] is dangerous

Comment: In my xml , It has only one attributes. If I use yours in loop,I get message because firstly I am getting node.  "   node := nodes_row.item[i];" this code  is selecting next node in loop